# What is the difference between blubbering and sobbing?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Mostly because I see these words used interchangeably, and wish to know the difference.

Comment: What do you see when you compare the dictionary definitions of the two terms?

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that of all the dictionaries I've checked so far, only [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blubber) adds what I consider to be a necessary caveat:

> **blubber** [verb] [I]   [informal] [disapproving]
>
> (UK informal *blub*)   to cry in a noisy way like a child:
>
> - *There he sat, cowering against the wall, blubbering like a child.*
> - *Oh stop blubbing! Your knee can't hurt that much.*

[AHD, Collins and R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blubber), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blubber), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blubber), and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/blubber_1) have merely *to sob noisily and/or unrestrainedly/uncontrollably*.

Nevertheless, the childish / disapproving qualification is warranted in my opinion; I'd rarely use the verb myself. 'Sobbing' is totally unmarked in this way, and can readily be used where the loud / violent crying is deemed fully justified. There is no hint of disapproval.